# DialogFragment with clear background (not dimmed)

Tags: android, background, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to get the background of a `DialogFragment` to be completely clear.

With setting the style item `android:windowIsFloating` to true (the default),
the `DialogFragment` displays exactly how I want it to, but has a very dimmed background.

By setting `android:windowIsFloating` to false, I get the clear background I want, but the DialogFragment blows up to about 95% of the screen,
leaving only a tiny gap around it where you can see through to the view it overlays.

I've tried ton's of tweaks and cannot seem to override this behavior.

Do I need to use a `PopupWindow` to achieve the desired effects, or are there some style
items that I can override ?

Comment: I just came across the LayoutParameter flag WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND. Hopefully this will do it...

Answer (score 85, accepted):

What works for me is to adjust the `WinowManager.LayoutParams` in `onStart()` of the [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html):

```
@Override public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams windowParams = window.getAttributes();
    windowParams.dimAmount = 0.90f;
    windowParams.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
    window.setAttributes(windowParams);
}
```

Comment: +1, works for me. For **no dim at all**, use `windowParams.dimAmount = 0;`. Also, you must do this in `onStart()`, not `onCreateView()`.

Comment: Why does it work only in `onStart()` why not in `onCreateView()`?

Comment: @zIronManBox The dialog is not yet rendered/instantiated in `onCreateView()`.

Comment: @Jonik No, you don't need to touch `windowParams.dimAmount`. Just remove `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND` from `windowParams.flags`

Comment: this workaround is still working 2021.11.18

Answer (score 8):

Create your own Customized dialog extends with `FragmentDailog`
and override this method

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    //set the dialog to non-modal and disable dim out fragment behind
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    return dialog;
}
```

NOTE: This answer works for me in case of `DialogFragment` and `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

Comment: works for me `window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)`

Answer (score 3):

You need to get a handle to your DialogFrament (sometime after .show is called),
and do this in a Posted Runnable:

```
DialogFragment dialog;

...

WindowManagerLayoutParams wlp = dialog.Dialog.Window.Attributes;
wlp.Flags &= ~WindowManagerFlags.DimBehind;
dialog.Dialog.Window.Attributes = wlp;
```

I got it from Aleks G's answer to [Changing position of the Dialog on screen android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467026/change-dialog-position-on-the-screen) .

Answer (score 1):

Even a simpler solution is to change the style in the onCreate of the DialogFragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, getTheme());
}
```

Comment: This removes dialog title as well