# Firebase Notification in Popup Dialog, in App Background Service

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

Is it possible to build Alert Dialog like Truecaller App Dialog, on Firebase Message received? is there any documentation. I want to show a Dialog on Notification received over other Apps as transparent.

Drawing over other apps, something like this. but with the firebase notification content.

refrence[image]

Thank you.

Comment: To implement your scenario you just need to search about Overlay dialog

Comment: The following link can help you with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36346185/showing-an-overlay-in-android

Comment: Is it possible to show overlay, When app is in Background! I'm really new to the android development can you help me with any reference/code snippet for notification. please

Comment: Yes it is possible to show the overlay dialog even when your application is in background