# How to create modal dialog box in android

Tags: modal-dialog, android

i want create modal dialog box for my application.

so when modal dialog box open the other activities are blocked. no event are done like back button press or home button press.

and put two option button in that dialog box cancel and ok.

Thank you...

Comment: Can you show your code which you tried?

Comment: my question is correct so what negative vote gave to me.

Comment: I didn't downvote! Just asked for code.

Comment: See the easiest and perfect answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15062022/256770

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are many kind of `Dialogs` in Android. Please take a look at [Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). I guess what you are looking for is something like `AlertDialog` . This is the example of how you can implement on `BackPress` button.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Do you want to logout?");
    // alert.setMessage("Message");

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //Your action here
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            }
        });

    alert.show();

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to implement it on `HOME` key ? Some links for your ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783960/call-method-when-home-button-pressed-on-android & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079691/overriding-the-home-button-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-choice

Comment: Fortunately you can't handle `HOME` key press. It would allow applications to do some ugly stuff.

Answer (score 10):

Use can use 
setCancellable(false);
setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
for the dialog itself, that should stop that dialog from closing by BACK and by tapping outside the dialog.

You can't override the HOME button.

Comment: Actually, you can override the home button... by making your application a "Launcher".

Answer (score 9):

Try this::

You need to create layout that you want to show in popup. you can create layout XML and use it like this:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
            View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_popup_layout, null);  
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                    layout, 
                       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

You can also provide click events of button like this:

```
ImageButton btnChoose = (ImageButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnChoose);
            btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
}
});
```

and show this popup like this: here you want to show this on button click then button view will be there.

```
 popupWindow.showAtLocation(anyview,Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```