# How to hold the activity when the dialog is open

Tags: android, dialog

I am working with Android, and I open a `Dialog` using `myDialog.show();` from the `Activity`, this Dialog has a `Button` and when I click that button the Dialog closes without problem using `this.hide();`.

this is the part of code where I have the question :

```
  myDialog.show();
  Toast.makeText(this, "the dialog is closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

the `Toast` is displayed during `myDialog` is open, and I thought that when `myDialog` is open, this hold my `Activity` and the Toast can not be displayed, but it is not the case.

So what I want is that `myDialog` once opened hold the `Activity` and when it is closed the `Activity` continue to the next instruction which is the `Toast`

Comment: I dont understand the question, where is your problem?

Comment: I want the Toast will be displayed once the myDialog  closed

Comment: Program execution does not stop on `myDialog.show();`. The dialog is run asynchronously. That is why the Toast is shown before dialog is close

Comment: @ramaral yes, but can I open it synchronously and hold my Activity until closing the dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120567/android-how-to-get-a-modal-dialog-or-similar-modal-behavior), and the solution that proposed is to create your `myDialog.setCancelable(false);`

Answer (score 2):

just Override `onDismiss` in your dialog and put your toast in there. onDismiss gets called when the dialog is closing.

of in your activity implement `OnDismissListener` and set the listener in your dialog

Comment: This is just an example but in my Toast I have to display a text comming from myDialog, so I have to wait until this Dialog were closed

Comment: the dialog is closed in on dismiss so either override that or use the onDismissListener like I said

Comment: Yes I anderstand and it is a good Idea, just I want to know, if there is another mode of opening the dialog, before I worked with Builder C++ 6, and I have a choice to display my Dialog letting the mainWindow continue execution next instructions OR display it and hold the mainWindows until the dialog is closed

Comment: No, there isn't.
Most of Android listeners and callbacks run on main thread, the same thread that paints the screen (main thread behaves like a message queue where each message can be a paint, onClick, onDismiss, onCreate, etc..). That's why you should rely on "future" callbacks to handle stuff like this.

Comment: @ivan.aguirre thank you Mr Ivan, yes Javist also said it... thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I find this [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/C4Dnl21f7Ic) :

If you want to literally not have the function that brings up the dialog return until the dialog is closed, you're in for some trouble. That's not the way the Android UI works.....